# Have React bootstrap component (popover) change position automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am currently using [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) to add Bootstrap React components to my app.

When the user clicks on the button, a popup appears, allowing the user to add an item to a list. It looks like the following:

[image]

When the user types in the input box and presses "Add", it adds a row to the div that the button is in. However, because the popover is added to the very end of `<body>`, the popover does not move as the number of rows increases. It looks like the following:

[image]

The applicable code looks like the following:

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="top" overlay={this.generatePopover()}>
  <Button bsSize="lg"> Add Income Source</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

where `this.generatePopover()` makes use of the `<Popover>` component.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
render() {
    return (
        <OverlayTrigger ref="trigger" trigger="click" placement="top" overlay={this.generatePopover()}>
            <Button bsSize="lg" onClick={this.addRow}> Add Income Source</Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
    );
}

addRow() {
    var self = this;
    // ... your logic
    this.setState({rows: this.state.rows.concat([])}, function() {
        // when DOM is already updated
        self.refs.trigger.hide();
        self.refs.trigger.show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `shouldUpdatePosition` to your OverlayTrigger. This options is unfortunately not documented :(

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="top" overlay={this.generatePopover()} shouldUpdatePosition >
  <Button bsSize="lg"> Add Income Source</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: This is no longer a prop of OverylayTrigger, any updated solutions?